# magento markup tag for m2epro templating

Tags: php, magento, m2e

i am working on a magento site that has the M2EPro Extension which has an ebay template in it. The page that was created by the previous developer has markup such as:

```
#ebay_name#
#sku#
#description#
{{block id="ebay_shipping"}}
```

Are these built into magento? Where can a get a list of other tags i can put into the html template? I have looked deeply into the magento documentation and cant find anything regarding this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are not built into magento, they can be seen through PHP or XML. A nice outline can be seen [here](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/web/magento-static-blocks/). As for the native magento blocks I am unable to find a set list of native Magento blocks. It's not very documented for whatever reason. You can poke around in the layout directory of your theme `app/code/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout` to find the XML files. There you will see something like:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

We can all this block in a CMS page or Static Block via the following:

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```

I hope this helps a little bit! Not a direct answer but at least it's a start!